# Правильный метод в java

Tags: java

Есть метод, который проверяет все выигрышные комбинации в игре "крестики-нолики". Его как-нибудь возможно разделить на несколько методов? Т.к. в этом варианте он выглядит громоздким (условия) и слишком много кода повторяется, а как я уже понял, в java крайне не рекомендуется писать повторяющийся код. Собственно, что можно сделать с этим методом, чтобы он соответствовал правилам java?

```
public Player getWinner() {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.getFiguresArray().length; i++){
            if (board.getFigure(i, 0) == board.getFigure(i, 1) &&
                    board.getFigure(i, 0) == board.getFigure(i, 2) &&
                    board.getFigure(i, 0) != null &&
                    board.getFigure(i, 1) != null &&
                    board.getFigure(i, 2) != null ) {
                if (players[0].getFigure() == board.getFigure(i, 0))
                    return players[0];
                return players[1];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < board.getFiguresArray().length; i++){
            if (board.getFigure(0, i) == board.getFigure(1, i) &&
                    board.getFigure(0, i) == board.getFigure(2, i) &&
                    board.getFigure(0, i) != null &&
                    board.getFigure(1, i) != null &&
                    board.getFigure(2, i) != null ) {
                if (players[0].getFigure() == board.getFigure(0, i))
                    return players[0];
                return players[1];
            }
        }
        if (board.getFigure(0, 0) == board.getFigure(1, 1) &&
                board.getFigure(0, 0) == board.getFigure(2, 2) &&
                board.getFigure(0, 0) != null &&
                board.getFigure(1, 1) != null &&
                board.getFigure(2, 2) != null ) {
            if (players[0].getFigure() == board.getFigure(1, 1))
                return players[0];
            return players[1];
        }
        if (board.getFigure(0, 2) == board.getFigure(1, 1) &&
                board.getFigure(0, 2) == board.getFigure(2, 0) &&
                board.getFigure(0, 2) != null &&
                board.getFigure(1, 1) != null &&
                board.getFigure(2, 0) != null ) {
            if (players[0].getFigure() == board.getFigure(1, 1))
                return players[0];
            return players[1];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: _в java крайне не рекомендуется писать повторяющийся код_ - нет, это справедливо для всех языков программирования. Во-первых, стоклеточные шашки довели бы вас до самоубийства. Во-вторых, при изменении кода (ошибка или доработка) пришлось бы менять код во всех одинаковых кусках кода.

Comment: 1. Выбираете клетку
2. Идете сначала в левую сторону по диагонали или по прямо от нее, затем в противоположную и считаете количество Х или О.
3. Если количество совпадает заданным вами числом - победа, если нет то, переходите на следующую клетку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private boolean isPossible(board board, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2,int x3, int y3){
return (  board != null &&
          board.getFigure(x1, y1) != null &&
          board.getFigure(x2, y2) != null &&
          board.getFigure(x3, y3) != null &&
          board.getFigure(x1, y1) == board.getFigure(x2, y2) &&
          board.getFigure(x1, y1) == board.getFigure(x3, y3));
}
```

Основной код

```
public Player getWinner() {
    for (int i = 0; i < board.getFiguresArray().length; i++){
        if (isPossible(board, i, 0, i, 1, i, 2) ) {
            if (players[0].getFigure() == board.getFigure(i, 0))
                return players[0];
            return players[1];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < board.getFiguresArray().length; i++){
        if (isPossible(board, 0, i, 1, i, 2, i)) {
            if (players[0].getFigure() == board.getFigure(0, i))
                return players[0];
            return players[1];
        }
    }
    if (isPossible(board, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2)) {
        if (players[0].getFigure() == board.getFigure(1, 1))
            return players[0];
        return players[1];
    }
    if (isPossible(board, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2)) {
        if (players[0].getFigure() == board.getFigure(1, 1))
            return players[0];
        return players[1];
    }
    return null;
}
```

думаю дальше сами сможете